# Exploring .app files on mac

Tags: macos, header-files

Can one get access to the application source files on mac? In Applications folder any .app file can be explored and there get access to the header files, is it all or can the class files be accessed too?

Comment: I dont think the header files are in there... im pretty sure its config plists, binaries and resources (translations, images, etc).

Comment: I have looked right now at two random apps and all the headers are there in the frameworks folder, plus all the resource files, such as images, translations and so on as you mentioned

Answer (score 2):

Unless a Mac application includes private frameworks (in the application bundle), which includes their headers (rare), no.

Most of the time, a Mac application will just contain the application's binary, as well as resources (icons, images, L10N, etc.).

You may disassemble the binary, if you know how to deal with assembly language.

If the application was built with Objective-C, you can use specific tools to produce a header file from the binary, with all the Objective-C interfaces.

Take a look at [ClassDump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/), for instance.

You may also use the `nm` command, on the application's binary, to get a list of the symbols it contains.